# Finding keypoints in an handwritten arrow

Tags: opencv, image-processing, conv-neural-network, keypoint

I have been trying to find two keypoints (head and tail) in arrows I have drawn,
I was wondering is there a simpler approach than training a CNN, such as a using a classic approach (opencv).
I have used this simple approach:

```
bi = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 5, 75, 75)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(bi, 2, 3, 0.02)
```

Here are the images, before:

[image]

After some simple image processing I get:

[image]

I could pick the two red dots with the longest euclidean distance (checking all combinations of pairs), but sadly for the self loop case it won't give me the correct result. can someone suggest me a better approach?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thank you all!

Comment: Corner detectors rarely yield useful/reliable corners.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ok got it, is there any other suggestion?

Comment: Did you read my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The image is quasi-binary. Consider binarization followed by thinning. You can find the tips and junctions. You can also follow the arcs.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer, Is the meaning of "thinning" is "eroding"? can you please elaborate more, it's unclear for me. thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinning_(morphology)